# How to type hint a tuple of callables when the default is empty

Tags: python, mypy

I'm type hinting like this:

```
some_kwarg: Tuple[Callable] = ()
```

but mypy raises

```
error: Incompatible default for argument "some_kwarg" (default has type "Tuple[]", argument has type "Tuple[Callable[..., Any]]")
```

I wouldn't want to put a dummy callable in the default kwarg so what's the right thing to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are type annotating it to accept a tuple of size exactly 1. Use:

```
Tuple[Callable, ...]
```

To indicate a homogeneous tuple of any size.

Comment: Or alternatively, `Sequence[Callable]` (comes to much the same thing)

Comment: Thanks! So question then, if I want a tuple of 10 callables exactly does `Tuple[Callable]` still cover it? Does `Tuple[Callable]` mean "1 or more" or "exactly 1" as you say? And if it's as you say, then how would you do exactly 10 (without abstracting away from `Tuple` specifically)?

Comment: @AlexanderSoare No. `Tuple[Callable]` means a tuple *with exactly one element*. If you meant only a tuple with exactly ten, then you need `Tuple[Callable, Callable, Callable, Callable, Callable, Callable, Callable, Callable, Callable, Callable]`

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your parameter is optional so you could use Optional from typing. I use the following and `mypy` diden't find any issues.

```
from typing import Tuple, Optional, Callable
def test_fun(some_kwarg: Optional[Tuple[Callable]]=None):
    pass
```

Comment: This isn't what `Optional` means in the context of type-checking. `Optional` doesn't mean "the container might be empty", it means "it might be this value, or it might be `None`". In this situation, we might have an empty `tuple`, but we'll never have a literal `None` value, so a hint using `Optional` would be incorrect.